# Affective Demonstratives and POS Tagging

Tags: nltk, grammar, corpus

Is there a way to accurately tag [affective](http://languagelog.ldc.upenn.edu/nll/?p=674) demonstratives in a corpus? Attempting a project using a Twitter corpus and I need to be able to sort through 200,000+ tweets to pick out the ones with affective demonstratives. I'd rather not do it by hand!

I'm using NLTK and Twython with [this](http://www.nltk.org/howto/twitter.html) whole process if that helps at all.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of an off-the-shelf solution, but this sounds like a classic NLP classification task. You'll need a sizeable corpus in which you (or someone else) have marked up the "affective demonstratives", and then you'll need to train a classifier and experiment with different features or feature selection algorithms. Look over the nltk book for details.

You would probably want to start by using a standard tagger to POS-tag your corpus; then you can use these tags (and anything else you think might be useful) as input features for your classifier.

Comment: Ahh that's what I was afraid of. Any idea how big the corpus will need to be? I'm fairly new at this, thanks for the help!

Comment: Couldn't say. It all depends on how often they come up in your corpus, how consistently you can hand-tag them, and how hard they are to distinguish (automatically) from regular demonstratives. And how much precision/recall you need to get, of course. You'll need a large enough corpus to train and test on separate subsets, so I wouldn't even try with less than 500 **affective** examples (so probably plenty more than 500 sentences); and I think you'll need several times that. Annotating a corpus is no trivial task. (contd.)

Comment: Manual annotation should go pretty fast, though. Pre-tag your corpus, then set up a good efficient workflow, budget several days to just annotate, and see how far you can get.